# Issue with high cpu usage with canvas and requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, requestanimationframe

I found a canvas animation with requestAnimationFrame that im trying to change to my needs and i had a huge issue with cpu usage.. going up to 80% and i started to shave off things i dont want or need. Im down to 40-50% cpu usage now so i would like some help with what i could do to optimize this code and reduce the cpu usage.

I have read about requestAnimationFrame and that it runs at 60fps or even as high as possible and mabye that has a big part in the performance, perhaps there is something i could do there?

```js
/**
 * Stars
 * Inspired by Steve Courtney's poster art for Celsius GS's Drifter - http://celsiusgs.com/drifter/posters.php
 * by Cory Hughart - http://coryhughart.com
 */

// Settings
var particleCount = 40,
 flareCount = 0,
 motion = 0.05,
 tilt = 0.05,
 color = '#00FF7B',
 particleSizeBase = 1,
 particleSizeMultiplier = 0.5,
 flareSizeBase = 100,
 flareSizeMultiplier = 100,
 lineWidth = 1,
 linkChance = 75, // chance per frame of link, higher = smaller chance
 linkLengthMin = 5, // min linked vertices
 linkLengthMax = 7, // max linked vertices
 linkOpacity = 0.25; // number between 0 & 1
 linkFade = 90, // link fade-out frames
 linkSpeed = 0, // distance a link travels in 1 frame
 glareAngle = -60,
 glareOpacityMultiplier = 0.05,
 renderParticles = true,
 renderParticleGlare = true,
 renderFlares = false,
 renderLinks = false,
 renderMesh = false,
 flicker = false,
 flickerSmoothing = 15, // higher = smoother flicker
 blurSize = 0,
 orbitTilt = true,
 randomMotion = true,
 noiseLength = 1000,
 noiseStrength = 1;

var canvas = document.getElementById('stars'),
 context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
 mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 },
 m = {},
 r = 0,
 c = 1000, // multiplier for delaunay points, since floats too small can mess up the algorithm
 n = 0,
 nAngle = (Math.PI * 2) / noiseLength,
 nRad = 100,
 nScale = 0.5,
 nPos = {x: 0, y: 0},
 points = [],
 vertices = [],
 triangles = [],
 links = [],
 particles = [],
 flares = [];

function init() {
 var i, j, k;

 // requestAnimFrame polyfill
 window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function( callback ){

    };
 })();


 // Size canvas
 resize();

 mouse.x = canvas.clientWidth / 2;
 mouse.y = canvas.clientHeight / 2;

 // Create particle positions
 for (i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
  var p = new Particle();
  particles.push(p);
  points.push([p.x*c, p.y*c]);
 }


 vertices = Delaunay.triangulate(points);


 var tri = [];
 for (i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
  if (tri.length == 3) {
   triangles.push(tri);
   tri = [];
  }
  tri.push(vertices[i]);
 }


 // Tell all the particles who their neighbors are
 for (i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
  // Loop through all tirangles
  for (j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++) {
   // Check if this particle's index is in this triangle
   k = triangles[j].indexOf(i);
   // If it is, add its neighbors to the particles contacts list
   if (k !== -1) {
    triangles[j].forEach(function(value, index, array) {
     if (value !== i && particles[i].neighbors.indexOf(value) == -1) {
      particles[i].neighbors.push(value);
     }
    });
   }
  }
 }


 // Animation loop
 (function animloop(){
  requestAnimFrame(animloop);
  resize();
  render();
 })();
}

function render() {
 if (randomMotion) {
  n++;
  if (n >= noiseLength) {
   n = 0;
  }

  nPos = noisePoint(n);

 }



 if (renderParticles) {
  // Render particles
  for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
   particles[i].render();
  }
 }


}

function resize() {
 canvas.width = window.innerWidth * (window.devicePixelRatio || 1);
 canvas.height = canvas.width * (canvas.clientHeight / canvas.clientWidth);
}



// Particle class
var Particle = function() {
 this.x = random(-0.1, 1.1, true);
 this.y = random(-0.1, 1.1, true);
 this.z = random(0,4);
 this.color = color;
 this.opacity = random(0.1,1,true);
 this.flicker = 0;
 this.neighbors = []; // placeholder for neighbors
};
Particle.prototype.render = function() {
 var pos = position(this.x, this.y, this.z),
  r = ((this.z * particleSizeMultiplier) + particleSizeBase) * (sizeRatio() / 1000),
  o = this.opacity;



 context.fillStyle = this.color;
 context.globalAlpha = o;
 context.beginPath();

 context.fill();
 context.closePath();

 if (renderParticleGlare) {
  context.globalAlpha = o * glareOpacityMultiplier;

  context.ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, r * 100, r, (glareAngle - ((nPos.x - 0.5) * noiseStrength * motion)) * (Math.PI / 180), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
 }

 context.globalAlpha = 1;
};

// Flare class


// Link class
var Link = function(startVertex, numPoints) {
 this.length = numPoints;
 this.verts = [startVertex];
 this.stage = 0;
 this.linked = [startVertex];
 this.distances = [];
 this.traveled = 0;
 this.fade = 0;
 this.finished = false;
};




// Utils

function noisePoint(i) {
 var a = nAngle * i,
  cosA = Math.cos(a),
  sinA = Math.sin(a),


  rad = nRad;
 return {
  x: rad * cosA,
  y: rad * sinA
 };
}

function position(x, y, z) {
 return {
  x: (x * canvas.width) + ((((canvas.width / 2) - mouse.x + ((nPos.x - 0.5) * noiseStrength)) * z) * motion),
  y: (y * canvas.height) + ((((canvas.height / 2) - mouse.y + ((nPos.y - 0.5) * noiseStrength)) * z) * motion)
 };
}

function sizeRatio() {
 return canvas.width >= canvas.height ? canvas.width : canvas.height;
}

function random(min, max, float) {
 return float ?
  Math.random() * (max - min) + min :
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}


// init
if (canvas) init();
```

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
   background: #375848;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%, #000000 100%);
}

#stars {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16rem;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ironwallaby/delaunay/master/delaunay.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.15/minified/require.js"></script>
<canvas id="stars" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Try resizing the canvas only on the `resize` event, instead of in your animation loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had two things to suggest, one of which someone already mentioned in a comment -- only resize your canvas on resize events.

The other was to compare the time of each call to your animation loop with the time of the last call, and only render again if a certain amount of time has passed -- say 16 milliseconds for about a 60 fps rate.

```
var lastRender = 0;

(function animloop(){
    requestAnimFrame(animloop);
    var now = Date.now();
    if (now >= lastRender + 16) {
        render();
        lastRender = now;
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, to compare the time of each call made little to no difference in cpu usage and made the animation flicker a lot. The first suggestion about only resizing the canvas on resize events, how would i proceed to do that. Im very new to canvas animation and kinda in the dark here.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("resize", resize);`, where `resize` is the resize method you already have defined.

Comment: Alright, my concern is where i want to place the eventlistener instead of the loop? Sorry if im overcomplicating stuff.

Comment: Add the listener, and place the resize function, just outside of the loop.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. How's the performance now? Did it make a difference? Cool animation effect, by the way. :)

Comment: The perfomance is the same.. mabye like 1% lower.. And the animation acts as if i just removed the resize from the loop and its really wierd heh :)

Comment: It could just be that this is a very CPU-intensive animation. You could get `Date.now()` just before calling `render()` and `Date.now()` just after, dump the difference to the console, and see how much time it takes to render one frame. If it takes, say, 8 msec to render each frame, and you're trying to animate at 60 fps, then you're going to get around 50% CPU usage.

Comment: would it be possible to mabye render at 30 or 15 fps instead?